# how to make prototype function of prototype function?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have fuction animal and I made some prototype method as well, code:

```
function Animal (name, energy) {
  this.name = name
  this.energy = energy
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function (amount) {
  console.log(`${this.name} is eating.`)
  this.energy += amount
}

Animal.prototype.sleep = function (length) {
  console.log(`${this.name} is sleeping.`)
  this.energy += length
}
Animal.prototype.play = function (length) {
  console.log(`${this.name} is playing.`)
  this.energy -= length
}
```

how to make a new prototype method (say hunt) of animal.play method, so that the new method is only accessible if it is called like animal.play.hunt() and not like animal.hunt()

Comment: `Animal.prototype.play.hunt = function () {...};`. It's called a static method, though normally this is created into a class/constructor.

Comment: it is working but now i cant use the function chaining with it. like animal.play().hunt()

Comment: If you want to chain, you've to return `Animal.prototype.play` from `play` method. Or give a name to the method: `Animal.prototype.play = function play (length) {...};`, and return `play`.

Comment: yes i am returning from play method. i am doing return this. edit: sorry its not in the code

Comment: `this` refers to the instance, not to `play` method itself. You just said you don't want to get `hunt` called by the instance ("_not like animal.hunt()_".

Comment: ... Or you can return `this.play` from `play`. Notice, that when you call `hunt` (directly or chained) `this` in `hunt` refers to `play`, not to the instance you originally called `play` with.

Comment: so how do i make sure that the hunt() can only be called after play(). eg animal.play().hunt() should be possible but animal.hunt() or animal.eat().hunt() should be possible

Comment: Umm ... I've just explained that in the comments above.